# Implementing JS WebWorkers Job Queue with worker termination

Tags: javascript, html, multithreading, ecmascript-6, web-worker

I'm trying to implement a job queue using web workers. The task is image decoding. Tasks will arrive at a rapid rate and take a small variable amount of time.

I wrote a simple queue spawning 4 workers and processing jobs which works well. However on iPad my code crashes the page after a while.

After much investigation I found out that for some reason iPad browsers do not properly/efficiently GC workers memory and with a very high volume of jobs end up crashing. (Another explanation can be that the code in the thread (jpeg decoding) leaks memory though I cannot find it in the profiler and the page never crashes on other desktop/devices).

What I found out is that if I terminate() each worker  after finishing a job and spawn a new one everything works fine on the IPad. So I am now attempting to create a job queue that spawns a new worker for each job.

The issue I am facing is worker creation is relatively costly (~40ms) and will end up competing with the stream of coming jobs on the main thread. My question is what is the best way to solve this and if there are any relevant existing solutions libraries ? should I move the queue manager to it's own webworker ? or maybe start with maxWorkers*2 and whenever a worker ends it will spawn it's replacement worker itself and send that to the queque manager together with the result ?

Any ideas appreciated thanks.

Comment: Within your workers, you can very slightly influence GC by setting your unused (large) objects to NULL. Try this prior to the kill/respawn option.

Comment: thanks Randy, I did try that, the iPad still crashes .. it is a very hard to debug issue as the page just reload :( I still don't fully understand it

Comment: What does `navigator.hardwareConcurrency` outputs on your device? For better perfs, you should not start this number - 1 workers simultaneously. But not sure the crash is related. Where is stored the data that will be decoded in each task? How is the result passed back to the main thread? All in all, I think it would help to see your actual code, or at least a minimal version of it.